# Does CRON execute scripts similarly to

Tags: display, tmux, cron, ubuntu-18.04

Does CRON execute scripts similarly to how a user is using an open session and sitting at the terminal for scripts that require such execution.

OR

Does CRON require the use of **tmux** and **screen**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands run with cron will run pretty much the same as if you had run them from a terminal session.  It does not require tmux or screen.

Cron is not for interactive commands, so as long as the command does not require interaction -- or has an automated way to intake such interactive data -- it should work without issue.

Cron will not get the full user environment when it runs. It doesn't run a login shell when it executes, so if the command you plan to run requires environmental settings from the users shell, you will probably need to wrap it in a script that provides those variables.

Comment: Thank you. From what I understand is CRON runs as a non-interactive non-login shell which runs the script and closes immediately once the script is finished? I came across several similar questions that said if the script or program requires tmux it must use either tmux or screen. Which is what I used before so I didn't have to wait for the script to end.